# Create custom template for KendoUI ListView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to create a custom template for ListView (I show products eShop in ListView). I wrote this code:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
    <div class="item">
    <div class="image">
        <a href='@Url.Action("GetDetails", "Products", routeValues: new {id =${ProductID}} )' target='_blank' class='pimg'>
            <img src="${ProductThumbnailImageUrl}" alt=" ${ProductTitle}"/>
        </a>
    <div class="price"> ${kendo.toString(ProductPrice, "n0")} </div>

    <div class="name">

</div>
    <div class="description_featured" style="min-height: 110px;">
        ${ProductDescription}

    </div>
    </div>
</div>

</script>

@(Html.Kendo().ListView(Model)
          .Name("listView")
          .TagName("div")
          .ClientTemplateId("template")
          .DataSource(dataSource =>
                      {
                          dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Products"));
                          dataSource.PageSize(12);
                          dataSource.ServerOperation(false);
                      })
          .Pageable()
             )
```

I get an error on `new {id = ${ProductTitle}}`.

Comment: Please check you have added all required Kendo and jQuery references to the application. and your template should be with in <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template"> </script>. I hope you did not miss those!

Comment: do you have a controller "Products" and does it has  action method "Products_Read" and does it return object with properties "ProductTitle", "ProductThumbnailImageUrl", "ProductPrice" and "ProductDescription"?

Comment: @ HaBo: yes in product controller  have Products_Read action . and when remove routeValues: new {id =${ProductID}} and run project , work fine.

Comment: did you try replacing new {id =${ProductID}} with new {id =#: ProductID #}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you use templates.
This is one on the template i recently used for my web site.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
       <div class="product">
            <img src='http://cdn.rbgx.net/images/skybazaar/products/medium/${ImageFileName}' alt="${Name} image" />
    <div class="productDeatails">
            <h3>#:Name#</h3>
     # if (EntityType == 2) { #
        Click to see products of this category
    # } else if(EntityType == 1) { #
     # if(parseFloat(SalePrice) > 0 && parseFloat(SalePrice) < parseFloat(Price)) { #
    Sale Price #: kendo.toString(SalePrice, "c")#
    # } else { #
     Price #: kendo.toString(Price, "c")#
    # } #
    # } #
        </div>
        </div>
    </script>
```

in your case for `${ProductTitle}`
use `#: ProductTitle #`